# Stripe Connect payment in iOS

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We want to integrate Stripe Connect with iOS application to transfer amount from one person to person.

Let's say, I want to transfer $100 to my sister's account using Stripe Connect Standalone/Managed Account. And we also want to take business commission from sender which includes stripe commission also.

We have gone through [Sharing Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers) also but won't be able to find any solution for Stripe Connect with iOS SDK.

We have also checked [iOS SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios).

Can anyone please guide us how to integrate Stripe Connect with iOS mobile app in above scenario?

How can we transfer payment to end customer?

Do we need to integrate through iOS SDK or web page?

Answer (score 2):

Stripe's [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) SDKs serve the same purpose in a mobile application as [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) do in a web application: they take payment information and produce a token in return.

Once the token has been created, it must then be sent to a backend server where it can be used in API requests sent with the secret key. You can't create charges or transfers directly from your mobile app -- that must be handled by an external server.

(Also, please note that there might be compliance issues with what you're trying to do. I recommend you reach out to [Stripe's support](https://support.stripe.com/email) to explain your usecase and make sure it's something that Stripe can support.)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily integrate Stripe Connect with your iOS app check the following link
https://github.com/gurunglaxman0/StripeConnect-iOS

Once you connect your stripe user id with server you can create charges and application fee using Stripe Api's from backend